# Added style files manually to geoserver's data_dir, but they don't appear in the GUI

Tags: geoserver

I have a geoserver instance into which I want to add many styles. Specifically, they are styles from a different instance.

I realize that I could do this via the API but I thought it would be easier to just bulk copy the style files from one data_dir into the other.

I copied the style files into the new instance's workspace's styles folder, which has the path:

```
/opt/geoserver/data_dir/workspaces/lc2-workspace/styles
```

An example style's XML file looks like this:

```
<style>
  <id>StyleInfoImpl--7d85fe9e:18bd86044f6:-61df</id>
  <name>lc2-style-99-system_load_factor</name>
  <workspace>
    <id>WorkspaceInfoImpl--6761a99c:189e51b8074:-7ff6</id>
  </workspace>
  <format>sld</format>
  <languageVersion>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
  </languageVersion>
  <filename>lc2-style-99-system_load_factor.sld</filename>
  <dateCreated>2023-11-16 14:27:47.940 UTC</dateCreated>
  <dateModified>2023-11-16 14:27:47.955 UTC</dateModified>
</style>
```

(There is an associated .sld file for each of them)

And the workspace's workspace.xml file looks like this:

```
<workspace>
  <id>WorkspaceInfoImpl--6761a99c:189e51b8074:-7ff6</id>
  <name>lc2-workspace</name>
  <isolated>false</isolated>
  <dateCreated>2023-08-11 14:59:36.44 UTC</dateCreated>
</workspace>
```

But they simply do not appear in the "Styles" tab.

I have tried restarting the service (rather I stopped and started the docker compose service running it), and I also tried clicking on "Reload" for "Configuration and catalog" in the "Server Status" tab of the GUI, but they still do not show up in the "Styĺes" tab, and they return 404 when requested via a WMS request.

Am I just out of luck here and I have to do it via the API? It seems to me like you should be able to just bulk-copy between data dirs like this, as long as you have the  tags right in the XML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well they wouldn't! You need to tell GeoServer that you want to add a new style based on the SLD file either through the GUI or the REST interface. This then allows GeoServer to create the necessary XML files that it uses to store the configuration.

Comment: I can understand why this would be the preferred method, but why is it that the GUI doesn't recognize the new files when they are added directly via the filesystem? The <id> tags seem to match correctly.

Comment: I'd guess there's more config stored some where else, maybe try adding one using REST and see exactly which files are changed

Comment: Alright, I've learned my lesson: that there more gears inside of geoserver than are worth mucking about with manually. I'll just stick to either using the API or hotswapping data directories when I want to do stuff like this.

Comment: **With all due respect to Ian**, I've been using your approach (copy files in OS level) in my work for more than 10 years and it works flawlessly: I manually create a layer and its style in the DEV Geoserver, test it and then copy the pertinent files to 2 TEST and 7 PROD Geoservers. A Geoserver reload catalog is all it takes for each one to 'see' the new creation. All you need to secure is that everything mentioned in those files must be the same across your maschines (e.g. workspace_info_implementation). If you need further analysis, let me know. HTH

Comment: This is a classic it might or might not work depending on how exact your copy is, there is absolutely no guarantee that it will continue to work in future versions. I would use the provided REST API which is designed for exactly this use case.